# How to add an Android fragment to an activity?

Tags: android, xml, layout, android-activity, fragment

I would like to add a fragment to my main activity, so I have this fragment class (TitleFragment.java):

```
package com.myapp.app1;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class TitleFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_title, container, false);
    }
}
```

Next is the actual content of my fragment, contained in `fragment_title.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
       <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/logo_iv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/logo_main"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And inside my `activity_main.xml` I have this snippet amongst the regular content of the activity:

```
<fragment 
            android:name="com.myapp.app1.TitleFragment"
            android:id="@+id/title_fragment"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Is this method a correct way to create a fragment? My app just crashes and the LogCat seems to indicate it's to do with inflating the fragment view, but I'm not sure.

By the way the reason for this fragment is to have the app logo (image and some updateable text) that exists on every page, is this a good method to do something like that? Sorry for my newbie questions.

Comment: Post your LogCat stack trace. And the Action Bar already has the app logo and text that you can change.

Comment: The android.developers site has a good guide. ::: There is no such thing "just" adding a fragment, usually the fragment is created depending on the screen size and orientation, otherwise an equivalent activity must be created. In the guide you will find code and explanations.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

i have started fragment from my `MainActivity`. main activity extends `FragmentActivity`. the way i have used is:

```
FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.body_frame, new MyFragment()).commit();
```

in your case, it should look like:

```
FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.title_fragment, new TitleFragment()).commit();
```

remember i have used an `FragmentActivity` to start `Fragment`. i have also used `android-support-v4.jar`
to support fragment in lower version OS. without `android-support-v4.jar`,
`FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();` may be look like : `FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();`

**Edited:**

you should modify your fragment class:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_title, container, false);
    // you can use findViewById() using the above 'view'
      ......................
      ....your code........
       ................
    return view;
}
```

Comment: I would up vote this but I don't have enough rep :( ^_^ Thanks, I had something very close to those three lines but not quite. I wonder if I should use the action bar rather than a fragment for my purposes though? Off to google!

Comment: I'd like to emphasize what is buried in one paragraph:   If only targeting API 11 and newer, can do `MainActivity extends Activity` rather than `MainActivity extends FragmentActivity`. That is, `Activity`s can access Fragments, no longer need `FragmentActivity`. This approach would not use android-support-v4.jar.  Instead of `= getSupportFragmentManager()`, do `= getFragmentManager()`.  I know this is mentioned in the answer, but it would be easy to overlook or misunderstand what was said.

Answer (score 6):

In fragment section add the following code:

```
tools:layout="@layout/fragment_title"
```

Here's an example:

```
<fragment 
    android:name="com.myapp.app1.TitleFragment"
    android:id="@+id/title_fragment"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_title />
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do that simply like this and declare the name of fragment:

```
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:name="com.example.ExampleFragment" />
```

Comment: woah this dumb question of mine is nearly 10 years old :D Yeah this is now the way to do it, especially useful with the Navigation library

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the activity that has the `activity_main.xml` layout extends `FragmentActivity` and not `Activity`.

Comment: and what about extending ActionBarActivity with AppCompatv7

Comment: @ToKra That should be fine. ActionBarActivity is a child of FragmentActivity. More recently, it's been deprecated and defers to AppCompatActivity, which is also a child of FragmentActivity.

Comment: This answer is outdated:  If targeting only API 11 and newer, `Activity` can be used, rather than `FragmentActivity`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onMenuItemClick(View clickedView, int position) {
    switch (position){
        case 1:
             fragmentChanger("Notifications",new notifyFragment());
           break;
        case 2:
             fragmentChanger("QR Code",new qrFragment());
            break;
        case 3:
            fragmentChanger("User ID",new MainFragment());
            break;
        case 4:
            fragmentChanger("Settings",new settingsFragment());
            break;
        default:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Clicked on position: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
    }
}

//function that does the trasaction when a fragment object is passed
//R.id.container is my default frame
public void fragmentChanger(String title, Object expectedFragment){
   // mToolBarTextView.setText(title);
    transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.container, (Fragment) expectedFragment);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
    transaction.commit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Tag you can add/Replace Fragment In Activity

```
private final static String BLANK_FRAGMENT_A= "BlankFragmentA";
private final static String BLANK_FRAGMENT_B= "BlankFragmentB";

private BlankFragmentA blankFragmentA;
private BlankFragmentB blankFragmentB;
```

Add Fragment

```
blankFragmentA= (BlankFragmentA) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(BLANK_FRAGMENT_A);
if (blankFragmentA== null) {
   blankFragmentA= new BlankFragmentA ();
   getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.frame_layout,blankFragmentA,BLANK_FRAGMENT_A).commit();
}
```

Replace Fragment

```
blankFragmentB= (BlankFragmentB) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(BLANK_FRAGMENT_B);
if (blankFragmentB== null) {
   blankFragmentB= new BlankFragmentB();
   getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace (R.id.frame_layout,blankFragmentB,BLANK_FRAGMENT_B).commit();
}
```